# Theme images not showing up after site migration

Tags: wordpress, migration

I've just made the migration of a Wordpress website to a new server (http://52.89.230.100/). The migration went fine, the only problem is that after it none of the theme images of the website are showing up.

The weird thing is that it is pointing to the right url - if I right click on the image area, copy the url and paste it on the browser, the image opens perfectly. But at the website itself it doesn't.

Where am I missing?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think u need to set permissions correctly

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: (I'm using an EC2 Instance server)

Comment: Are u having ftp/ssh acces?

Comment: Yes, via Filezilla

Comment: try changing permissions by right clicking on folder/file. Still I am not sure it is exactly the problem.. but just try

Comment: Check the browser console on your site. The following is showing:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

Comment: @MirzaP, where should I do that? At the Amazon management console? Or Wordpress?

Comment: I believe in the Amazon management console App Settings